# I bricked my flash drive with u3-tool. Is it fixable?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, firmware, u3

I was playing around with the linux command line tool `u3-tool` to mess with a flash drive. This tool lets you do firmware level things to flash drives that support it. One option was `u3-tool -e` which supposedly enables the security. It asks you to give it a password to secure the drive with.

What should have happened from here was I should have been able to do `u3-tool -d` or `... -R` to undo this. Instead, immediately after doing `... -e`, the flash drive stopped responding. Everything that tried to use it said "Medium not found". Absolutely everything. U3-tool, dd, mkfs, parted, you name it. All giving that same error.

The only reference to it's existence is that `/dev/sdb` exists, and it has an entry in `lsusb`. Nothing would make use of it though, read or write. Doesn't even show up in `blkid`.

Is the drive done for? Or is there a way to save it?

Comment: "This tool lets you do firmware level things to flash drives **that support it**".  Do you know for a fact that your drive is one that supports it?  I suspect that if u3-tool can't see the drive, it's just bricked.

Comment: @fixer1234 Yes it does support it. The drive is advertised as a U3 device. I was using it to flash ISO files to the drive's CD partition without any issue. The issue came when I tried enabling the security, and no tool ever recognized it again after that.